# Tibco EMS on remote machine

Tags: tibco-ems

I am working with Tibco ems , I am able to send message to the queue successfuly where Tibco is running on localhost:7222.
But I want to run tibco server in remote machine say on Openshift or cloudfoundry.

How this can be done?

Thanks a lot in advance.

~Yash

Answer (score 0):

Install and start EMS on the remote machine. By default it will use the same port 7222. Make sure you can reach the remote machine from your local machine and make sure port 7222 is opened on the firewall. Then just use the syntax "tcp://remote.machine.domain.com:7222" and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that and let you know if any problem occurs. thanks for the response.

Comment: Hi, I have tried connecting to remote IP after installing it locally using command:                                                    Addprop factory sample.qcf url=”tcp://< remotehost:port>                      but when i run client from outside , means from other machine where tibco is not installed and running, it is not connecting with remote tibco server. Am i doing it right? or there is some other way to do? thanks in advance

Comment: Connection problems are always hard to debug. Can you ping remotehost? Can you open a telnet session on remotehost:port? Also, when you said Tibco is not installed and running on the other machine, realize that you *do* need the libraries on that machine. It doesn't have to be running, but installing Tibco will ensure you have the libraries.

Comment: Hi, Thanks again for the response, ping is working fine from other machine. In my client project i have added tibcrypt.jar,tibjms.jar,jms.jar , still its not connecting with the Tibco server running some where else. any help will be really appreciated.. Thanks again

Comment: I'm sorry, there are too many variables to give you a constructive answer. Did you check the firewall? What kind of error message are you getting?

Comment: Hi Pascal, Thanks again, let me explain you what I want to achieve in detail:                                                                  I have installed Tibco EMS server running on my machine at tcp://localhost:7222 , I have client application on public cloud like openshift/Cloudfoundry. I gave my app's ip as remote host which is present in cloud to run Tibco using "addprop" command. But when I run client which is there in public cloud to send message to Tibco EMS its giving: Failed to connect to the server tcp://23.22.16.44:7222 , any pointer on that will be very helpful, thanks a ton!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by [I gave my app's ip as remote host which is present in cloud to run Tibco using "addprop" command.]

Comment: My apps deployed URL in OpenShift cloud is this "tibcotest-abc.rhcloud.com" which runs in Jboss container that has host ip like 127.0.123.98 . I gave this Ip as remote host. I have also tried giving "tibcotest-abc.rhcloud.com" also as remote host but no success. :(